# Parse push notifications when data changes

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, push-notification

This is a general question about the design direction. I am working on a weather app right now, I have user accounts, weather data from web server. I am able to retrieve the weather to the app and post these data in Parse. What I really want is that if the temperature is out of a certain range, send a push notification back to the app. So my question is how can I receive this notification when the app is not running or running in the background? Any thoughts, directions, keywords would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Parse [Cloud Code](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#jobs), to send a push notification when the server is notified about the change. One way I can think of is to schedule a job (Look at you console - Core -> Jobs) that will run let's say every hour and will check the temperature and send a push if it meets one of your conditions.

Good Luck